# Don't know why label is not updating using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, authentication, logic, label

I am a beginner to python and trying to make a simple log in system for a school program together with it's GUI.

I did a good job since I am a beginner in python (and coding in general) and I am trying to learn to work with tkinter.

I have figured everything out except when I tried to make the program change the label text when the user "`access = True`".

Here is the code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

usernamelist = ["bob123","tim321","me","duda"]
passwordlist = ["banana","apple","password123","duda2000"]


def checklogin():
    global access
    global mode
    username = entuser.get()
    password = entpass.get()
    userfound = False
    if username == "admin":
        if password == "allowmein":
            access = True
            mode = "admin"
        else:
            lberror.config(text="Incorrect password, try again")
            entpass.delete(0, END)
    else:
        for i in range(len(usernamelist)):
            if username == usernamelist[i]:
                userfound = True
                if password == passwordlist[i]:
                    access = True
                else:
                    lberror.config(text="Incorrect password, try again")
                    entpass.delete(0, END)
    if userfound == False and username != "admin":
        lberror.config(text="Username not found, try again")
        entuser.delete(0, END)
        entpass.delete(0, END)
    if access == True:
        lberror.config(text= "Access Granted")
        sleep(1)
        mainlog.destroy()
        return access
        return mode


access = False
mode = "student"

mainlog = Tk()
mainlog.title("Maths Quiz Login")
lbuser = Label(mainlog, text= "Username: ")
lbpass = Label(mainlog, text= "Password: ")
entuser = Entry(mainlog,)
entpass = Entry(mainlog, show="*")
logbtn = Button(mainlog, text= "Login", command= checklogin)
lberror = Label(mainlog, text= "")

lbuser.grid(row=0, column=0)
lbpass.grid(row=1, column=0)
entuser.grid(row=0, column=1)
entpass.grid(row=1, column=1)
logbtn.grid(row=2, column=1)
lberror.grid(row=3,column = 0, columnspan = 2)

mainlog.geometry("250x150+100+100")

mainlog.mainloop()
```

When I am trying to run the code the `lberror` label appears to obey all commands when ordered to show incorrect password or username not found when the respective events happen, but it fails to show access granted and I tried to look for explanations and I couldn't manage to find.

Comment: Thank you so much Keren! I didn’t know about that! It was just what I was looking for, Imense gratitude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be destroying the window after you change the label to "Access Granted": `mainlog.destroy()`

If you remove destroying the window, "Access Granted" is displayed.

If you really want the window to be destroyed after logging in successfully, add `mainlog.update()` before `sleep(1)`.

```
if access == True:
        lberror.config(text= "Access Granted")
        mainlog.update()
        sleep(1)
        mainlog.destroy()
        return access
        return mode
```

Comment: If that answered your question, please consider upvoting or marking the answer as accepted.